# Longest Increasing Subsequence. Where is the error?

Tags: java, dynamic

I have been studying up of a tehnical interview and was doing DP problems. I came across the Longest Increasing Subsequence problem and i went straight into doing some recursion. I came up with this solution which I thought to be pretty straight forward, but it is showing some errors. However i cant understand where they might be. I read some of the discussed solutions and I understand how they work, but i cant understand where the mistake is on my part. Any help could be great!

Here's my solution.

````
    public static int lengthOfLIS(int[] nums) {
    return lengthOfLIS(nums, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  public static int lengthOfLIS(int[] nums, int carry, int index, int max){
    if(nums.length == 0){
      return 0;
    }
    if(index == nums.length - 1){
      return carry;
    }
//Checks if nums[index] is bigger than the max which is the last item to be checked.
    int temp_carry = carry;
    if(nums[index] > max){
      temp_carry++;
      max = nums[index];
    }

//Here i iterate through all the values starting from index and at the same time, 
//start a recursive call from zeroes to the next digit, and ask them to return the max between both calls.
    for(int i = index; i<nums.length; i++){
      max = Math.max(lengthOfLIS(nums, temp_carry, index+1, max), lengthOfLIS(nums, 0, index+1, nums[index+1]));
    }
    return max;
  }```
````

Comment: What are the errors? Did you try debugging your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a couple of problems.

Firstly ...

> `if(index == nums.length - 1) { return carry; }`

This is going to effectively ignore your last value in the array. If your last value is greater that `max` then your are not going to be increment `carry`, so you will always potentially short your length count by 1.

The next problem is your `for` loop...

> ```
> for(int i = index; i<nums.length; i++){
>   max = Math.max(lengthOfLIS(nums, temp_carry, index+1, max), lengthOfLIS(nums, 0, index+1, nums[index+1]));
> }
> ```

Honestly not really sure what you are trying to achieve here as it's actually quite confusing. The bigger issue is that you are completely ignoring `i`, which means that regardless of the number of runs of your loop, the values being passed to `lengthOfLIS` are going to be exactly the same for each loop iteration. Also, if you ever managed to hit the condition `if(index == nums.length - 1)` then you `return carry`, which means you are going to perform the you `Math.max` function on the returned `carry` value, but this is quite different from what you are using `max` for, as you are using `max` to denote the current maximum number at the end of your LIS. So all of a sudden your `max` becomes your `carry`, which just causes some mental back-flips.

The point of the Longest Increasing Subsequence (LIS) problem is to find the length of the longest sub-sequence of a given sequence such that all elements of the sub-sequence are sorted in increasing order, meaning that the LIS of { 10, 22, 9, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60 } is { 10, 22, 33, 50, 60 } (length = 5)

Try this...

```
public int lengthOfLIS(int[] nums) {
    return lengthOfLIS(nums, 0, 0, -1);
}

public int lengthOfLIS(int[] nums, int carry, int index, int max){
    if(nums.length == 0){
        return 0;
    }

    if(nums[index] > max) {
        carry++;
        max = nums[index];
    }

    int max_carry = carry;
    for (int i = index; i < (nums.length - 1); i++) {
        int temp_carry = lengthOfLIS(nums, carry, i + 1, max);
        if (temp_carry > max_carry) {
          max_carry = temp_carry;
        }
    }
    return max_carry;
}
```

Also just notice that the initial call `lengthOfLIS(nums, 0, 0, -1)` has a `-1` this is because your sequence could start with a zero ... { 0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15}, of which the LIS is { 0, 2, 6, 9, 11, 15 } (length = 6).

Comment: Thank you! That is all very clear, I had a hunch that my weird max function was gonna be the problem. Cheers!